# PHP MySQL Error Setting

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wamp, php-5.3

I have developed some php/mysql code on linux machine, and it runs fine. On client's machine running `wamp` server on windows,  same operation gives a mysql error - which Php is displaying neatly in a tabular format. The error is in a mysql query with INSERT, pertaining to Duplicate Keys.   (*I know I can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but that is not the issue*). **Problem is, the code is supposed to handle errors gracefully.**

It **does** on my linux machine, but on client's wamp - it displays  *html tables* with error details. I tried `try` and `catch` around the function call, but that also does not prevent the error from getting displayed in the browser (the PHP file is supposed to emit json data for ajax calls,  that is why I cannot afford to have those error display by PHP).

Also, in the php file, I have

`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

and still, since its a mysql error, it rightly does not throw any php error on linux, but does on windows.

**So basically, I want to know what PHP setting (or something else?) on client's machine could be causing the MySQL error to be propagated / processed by PHP, and how to turn it off.**

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Comment: Can you show us the entire error message? (To try to figure out where it is originating from)

Comment: you are setting 'display_errors' to `1` thus showing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your php.ini and look at these values:

```
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_format=1
mysql.trace_mode = On
pdo_mysql.debug = On
```

If they are there, disable them

Comment: It was indeed issue with xdebug and another extension.

Answer (score 0):

its better to make error_reporting(0); in start of your code when you put your code on live server , its is better to hide un necessary errors and notifications

Comment: It's true that's best, but it won't make the website function.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your MySQL version numbers are the same!

If you are using mysqli try having the following:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
```

If you want to turn it on with the Linux stack, try something like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

error_reporting(E_ERROR); OR error_reporting(0);
```